# Display only price of Custom Attribute of a product in Virtuemart

Tags: jquery, joomla, virtuemart

I am creating a mobile phone repairs site for a client and just wanted to ask if anyone knew how to display the price only of a Attribute set on a product. For example:

I have an iPhone, there can be 3 repairs, screen, power and misc. Each with it's own price.

I have 3 hidden div containers that show when the user hovers over specific points on the image of the product. These div containers also contain a "Add To Cart" button. I would like the price of the repair to be displayed below it. ( The prices are defined in the Attributes set for each product. )

I did use, $("vmCartAttributes).hide() to hide all of the custom attributes off the page, now I only want to show the price. So like, hover over the screen, show screen div and display the price associated with that attribute and imagemap point.

I hope this is clear enough.

Will post code if you need it.

Thankyou in advance,

Ross.

```
<div id="prodtitle">
<?php echo $product_name, $edit_link ?>
<p>Please hover over the image to see repairs.</p>
</div>

<br style="clear:both;" />
<table border="0" style="width: 100%;">
 <tbody>
<tr>
    <?php  if( $this->get_cfg('showManufacturerLink') ) { $rowspan = 5; } else {   $rowspan =     4; } ?>
 <td width="33%" rowspan="<?php echo $rowspan; ?>" valign="top"><br/>
 </table>

 <div id="detailwrap" style="text-align:center;">

<img class="prodimage" name="<?php echo $product_full_image ?>"    src="components/com_virtuemart/shop_image/product/<?php echo $product_full_image ?>" id="<?php echo $product_full_image ?>" usemap="<?php echo $product_full_image ?>" alt=""/>

<div id="detail">
<?php echo $product_description ?>

<div class="screen"><strong>Screen</strong>

<br/>Broke your screen?
<br/>We can fix that.

<form action="<?php echo $mm_action_url ?>index.php" method="post" name="addtocart" id="addtocart<?php echo $i ?>" class="addtocart_form" <?php if( $this->get_cfg( 'useAjaxCartActions', 1 ) && !$notify ) { echo 'onsubmit="handleAddToCart( this.id );return false;"'; } ?>>
<div class="vmCartDetails"><input name="product_id" value="<?php echo $product_id ?>" type="hidden" />

    <input id="quantity<?php echo $product_id ?>" name="quantity[]" value="1" type="hidden" /> 
    <input class="addtocart_button" value="Add to cart" title="Add to cart" type="submit" />
    <input name="flypage" value="shop.flypage.tpl" type="hidden" /> 
    <input name="page" value="shop.cart" type="hidden" /> 
    <input name="manufacturer_id" value="1" type="hidden" /> 
    <input name="category_id" value="<?php echo  @$_REQUEST['category_id'] ?>" type="hidden" /> 
    <input name="func" value="cartAdd" type="hidden" /> 
    <input name="option" value="com_virtuemart" type="hidden" /> 
    <input name="Itemid" value="1" type="hidden" /> 
    <input name="set_price[]" type="hidden" /> 
    <input name="adjust_price[]" type="hidden" /> 
    <input name="master_product[]" type="hidden" />
    <input name="Repairs<?php echo $product_id ?>" id="Repairs_field" value="Screen" type="hidden" />
    <!--<input type="hidden" name="custom_attribute_fields[]" value="Screen<?php echo $product_id ?>" />-->
</form>
</div>
</div>

<div class="power"><strong>Power</strong>

<br/>Phone not turning on?
<br/>We can fix that.

<form action="<?php echo $mm_action_url ?>index.php" method="post" name="addtocart" id="addtocart<?php echo $i ?>" class="addtocart_form" <?php if( $this->get_cfg( 'useAjaxCartActions', 1 ) && !$notify ) { echo 'onsubmit="handleAddToCart( this.id );return false;"'; } ?>>
<div class="vmCartDetails"><input name="product_id" value="<?php echo $product_id ?>" type="hidden" />

    <input id="quantity<?php echo $product_id ?>" name="quantity[]" value="1" type="hidden" /> 
    <input class="addtocart_button" value="Add to cart" title="Add to cart" type="submit" />
    <input name="flypage" value="shop.flypage.tpl" type="hidden" /> 
    <input name="page" value="shop.cart" type="hidden" /> 
    <input name="manufacturer_id" value="1" type="hidden" /> 
    <input name="category_id" value="<?php echo  @$_REQUEST['category_id'] ?>" type="hidden" /> 
    <input name="func" value="cartAdd" type="hidden" /> 
    <input name="option" value="com_virtuemart" type="hidden" /> 
    <input name="Itemid" value="1" type="hidden" /> 
    <input name="set_price[]" type="hidden" /> 
    <input name="adjust_price[]" type="hidden" /> 
    <input name="master_product[]" type="hidden" />
    <input name="Repairs<?php echo $product_id ?>" id="Repairs_field" value="Power" type="hidden" />
    <!--<input type="hidden" name="custom_attribute_fields[]" value="Power<?php echo $product_id ?>" />-->
</form>
</div>
</div>

    <!-- Not Implemented Yet -->
<div class="battery">Battery</div>
<div class="case">Case</div>
<div class="misc">Misc</div>




</div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, before I do anything, is tell you that this isn't a php question, this is a jquery question. Second of all, I wouldn't make those buttons those way as the customer might not find the buttons at all! Also, what does  `$("vmCartAttributes)` mean? First of all, no closing quotes, but I'll accept that, but also no definition of is it a Id, or class, or something, and I'm pretty sure there is no such html tag called **vmCartAttributes**, so i'm going to downvote this question for bad code, also incorrect tagging. However, I will do my best to help you, but I won't do anything about the html tag problem, because if it works for you, then it should work again, though I don't know why it would, also I need the element which will contain the price, and the actual tag which contains the price. Try using the following jquery code:

```
$("vmCartAttributes").mouseover(function(){
var price=$(this).attr('priceattribute');
$("pricecontainer").text(price);
}).mouseout(function(){
$("pricecontainer").text("");
});
```

Replace **pricecontainer** with the element that will show the price and **priceattribute** with the attribute that contains the price.

Comment: Okay I accept that, sloppy typing on my end :/. The $(".vmCartAttributes") is a drop down menu containing all of the Attributes, such as "Screen - £50" and "Power - £20" I hid it because I don't want the customers picking it from a dropdown. The price and title for each repair is set in the back-end and is added onto the base price of the product. In this case there is no base price, so when the customer adds the repair to the cart it is 0+{repair}.

Comment: I'm just having trouble finding the price attribute thats all, I know "vmCartAttributes" is the type, title and price. I was just needing to output the price on its own.

Comment: RossDoughty, I'm not fully comprehending what is going on. Could you please post your code. jsfiddle is a good idea. http://jsfiddle.net Save it, and paste the link here.